# Find all "steady-state" solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations

> The number of individuals in a certain population (in arbitrary real units) obeys, at discrete time intervals, the equation $$y_{n+1} = y_n(2-y_n) \hspace{2 mm}\text{for} \hspace{1 mm} n = 0,1,2,\ldots,$$ 
>   where $y_0$ is the initial population.
>
> (a) Find all "steady-state" solutions $y^*$ such that, if $y_0 = y^*,$ then $y_n = y^*$ for $n = 1,2,\ldots$.
>
> (b) Prove that if $y_0$ is any number in $(0,1)$, then the sequence $\{y_n\}$ converges monotonically to one of the "steady-state" solutions found in (a).

**My question**: Is a "steady-state" solution exactly as they describe it? A solution $y^*$ such that $y_n = y^*$ for $n = 1,2,\ldots$?

Comment: Yes, or equivalently, solve $y_{n+1} = y_n$ which will give solutions $\{0,1\}$.

Comment: We get $y_n = y_n(2-y_n) \implies y_n = 0$ or $y_n = 2$. Where does the $1$ come from in the set?

Comment: If $y_n = 2$ then $y_n = 0$? How did you get $y_n = 2$???

Comment: Oh, I see. I get the same solutions then.

Comment: The second part of the question asks, "Prove that if $y_0$ is any number in $(0,1)$, then the sequence ${y_n}$ converges monotonically to one of the steady-state solutions found in (a)."

Comment: Add it to the question and I will answer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(x) = x (2-x)$. Note that $f$ is concave, $f'(x) = 2(1-x)$ and has a maximum at $x=1$, hence
$f(x) \le 1$ for all $x$. Furthermore, $f'(x) \ge 0$ for $x \le 1$ so $f$
is non decreasing on $(-\infty,1]$.

Hence if $y_n \le 1$, then $y_{n+1} =f(y_n)\le 1$ and $y_{n+1} \ge y_n$.

Hence $y_n$ is a bounded non decreasing sequence and such sequences have
limits. So suppose $y_n \to y$, then by continuity $y=f(y)$ and so we must
have $y \in \{0,1\}$ (since these are the only solutions of $y=f(y)$).

In fact, if $y_0=0$ then $y_n = 0$ for all $y$
and
if $y_0 \in (0,1]$, then the above shows that $y_n \to 1$.